# Liquid: Assigning and capturing existing custom attribute in the control flow code block

Tags: conditional-statements, shopify, liquid

The purpose of this control flow block is checking to see if the existing level attribute is blank or an empty string, if it is, I would like to assign a default Level 1 to the code block. If the level attribute exists and is not blank, I would like to grab the current value of the customer's level. Somehow the Liquid engine is throwing an error in my code.

Can someone pinpoint where I've done wrong in my code? Thanks so much!

```
{% if customer.level == blank or customer.level =='' %}
  {% capture customer.level %}Level 1{% endcapture %}
  Hey! Your rewards level is: {{ customer.level }}

{% else %}
  Customer level is: {{ customer.level }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: From where you are getting the level attribute ? [Shopify Docs](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/customer) do not have level attribute for Customer object.

Comment: What is the error into liquid code when you add it to website?

Answer (score 0):

In Shopify's Liquid, **objects cannot be changed**. Your attempt to assign a value to `customer.level` is failing because you are not allowed to overwrite, delete or add values in something like the `customer` object.  (The `.` between `customer` and `level` indicates that "level" is a property of the "customer" object - `customer.level` does not represent a single variable on its own)

To fix the code, all you need to do is come up with a variable name that does not use the `.` character (or any other punctuation that can be interpreted by the code parser).  For example, naming your variable `customer_level` (using an underscore) should do the trick for you.

---

Also note that `level` is not a property of a customer object in Shopfiy, and you cannot add arbitrary fields to the core object types. I would recommend storing your level as either a tag or a metafield on the customer if you aren't already.  Note that assigning an appropriate tag or metafield cannot be done through the Liquid code, it has to be added by some app or process that has appropriate permissions.